# C# String array

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming, I recently started a computer science degree and I'm struggling a bit with the code, I am currently learning c#.

I am trying to get a string in an array to cut down on the amount of code and make it easier to format it in the console.

my code is:

```
 string [] sInvite = new string[]
         {
            "*********************************************"

                               +sGuest+
                    "is invited to the wedding of:"
                    + sBride + " and " + sGroom +
                "On Saturday 17 July 2016 at 2:00pm",

            "*********************************************"
         };
```

This is how I output it

```
Console.WriteLine(sInvite);
```

and this is the actual output in the console, obviously not what I wanted

```
system.String[]
```

any ideas on how I can get this to work, or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need to define this as an array?

Comment: Note that formatting this in your code won't format the output.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't really need to have it as an array, but instead of having each line as a separate string I would like it all in a single array. I understand I wont effect the formatting but it would make it easier a bit for me to do it, I think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a verbatim string like this:

```
string sInvite = @"

*********************************************

                   " + sGuest + @"
        is invited to the wedding of:
        " + sBride + @" and " + sGroom + @"
    On Saturday 17 July 2016 at 2:00pm

*********************************************";

Console.WriteLine(sInvite);
```

Comment: I was just going to recommend the same

Comment: I didn't see you answer =/

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for, I didn't really need It declaring as an array, I'm just trying to understand the keywords we're using and the different ways they are used.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using C# 6 then you can take the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33188547/1663001) from Yacoub Massad and instead use [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx):

```
string sInvite = $@"
*********************************************

                   {sGuest}
        is invited to the wedding of:
        {sBride} and {sGroom}
    On Saturday 17 July 2016 at 2:00pm

*********************************************";
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a string array containing a single element. You might as well just store that string as a string and print it. One thing you could do, if you want to keep using an array, is string.Join() the array elements together with a separator like \n. Then print that resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a string array in this case. You could use a verbatim string, like this

```
 string sInvite = 
     @"*********************************************"

                           +sGuest+
                "is invited to the wedding of:"
                + sBride + " and " + sGroom +
            "On Saturday 17 July 2016 at 2:00pm",

        "*********************************************";
```

The **@** allows you to write a `string` in two or more lines.

If you insist in use array, you can do `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", sInvite));`, it will convert your array in a `string` using the first as a separator for the array positions.

Answer (score 0):

I went on different route than all the other answers here to make sure that your text was always centered. I guessed that you wanted that from the way you formatted your code. So here's my answer:

```
int width = 45;
string sGuest = "Nasreddine";
string sBride = "Jane";
string sGroom = "John";

Console.WriteLine(new String('*', width));
Console.WriteLine(Center(sGuest, width));
Console.WriteLine(Center("is invited to the wedding of:",width));
Console.WriteLine(Center(sBride + " and " + sGroom, width));
Console.WriteLine(Center("On Saturday 17 July 2016 at 2:00pm", width));
Console.WriteLine(new String('*', width));
```

And this is the function that makes sure that the text is centered:

```
public static string Center(string str, int length)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    {
        return new String(' ',length);
    }

    if (str.Length >= length)
    {
        return str;
    }

    var halfDiff = (length - str.Length)/2.0;
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", new String(' ', (int) Math.Floor(halfDiff)), str) ;
}
```

And here's a [**live demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DEVClJ)

Comment: Thanks, you were correct about me wanting it centered, also thanks for the link to .NetFiddle that could come in handy

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you do not need an array to reduce the code. Secondly the answers given prior to this one are a new way of doing what you want to achieve i.e verbatim string. Here is the old fashioned way of doing it:

```
var string1 = String.Format(@"
*********************************************
                  {0}
        is invited to the wedding of:
             {1} and {2}
    On Saturday 17 July 2016 at 2:00pm

*********************************************",sGuest,sBride,sGroom);
```

`Console.Writeline(string1);`